# Prevent escape characters when rendering JSON in Perl Mojolicious

Tags: json, perl, escaping, mojolicious

I have a Mojolicious controller that calls

```perl
$controller->render_to_string(json => { %{$hashref} });
# or
$controller->render_to_string(json => $hashref);
```

The `$hashref` contains characters that are being escaped when written to the JSON object.
For example:

```perl
my $hashref = {
  path => '/path/to/file'
}
```

Which are being output as:

```json
{
  "path": "\\/path\\/to\\/file"
}
```

Is there a way to inform the `render_to_string()` method not to interpolate/escape these values?

I should mention that the actual strings are MD5 hashes.

Comment: What is the purpose of first expanding the hash with `%{ $hashref }` and then turning it back into a hash ref with `{  ... }`? Why not just use `json => $hashref`? If the problem is having several instances of the hash content, use a sub, or a lexically scoped hash definition.

Comment: A bit of overzealous dereferencing on my part, but when replaced with the simpler  `$controller->render_to_string( json => $hashref );` I'm still met with the same escaped values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering JSON, Mojolicious escapes `/` characters to prevent [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). This is mentioned in the [documentation of `Mojo::JSON`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/JSON#DESCRIPTION):

> The character `/` will always be escaped to prevent XSS attacks.
>
> ```
> "</script>" -> "<\/script>"
> ```

In practice, [this is done](https://metacpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/source/lib/Mojo/JSON.pm#L224) by `Mojo::JSON` itself, by opposition to "this is done by Mojolicious automatically every time it renders JSON content". This means that 1) there is no clean way to prevent this behavior when you do `->render( json => ... )`, and 2) the fix is simply to use another JSON module to do the encoding, and specify `format => 'json'` in the call to `render` (which will cause the headers of the response to contain `Content-Type: application/json`, as explained in [`Mojolicious::Guides::Rendering`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Content-type)):

```
use JSON qw( encode_json );

$controller->render(text => encode_json($hashref), format => 'json');
```

If you just want to render to a string with `$controller->render_to_string` (as you've done in your question), then you can omit `format => 'json'` (anyways, `format` [is ignored](https://metacpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/source/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm#L150) by `render_to_string`):

```
use JSON qw( encode_json );

my $json = $controller->render_to_string(text => encode_json($hashref));
```